# Why doesn't {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if} return a 404 header?

Tags: redirects, 404, error-pages

Under Design > Templates > Global Template Preferences I have Strict URLS set to yes and I've defined the 404 page (It lives at /errors/404).

We're running EE 2.8.1 and PHP 5.3.27

Something like http://site.com/foo displays the 404 template and properly returns a 404 header.

This URL exists and displays content properly http://site.com/groups/studies/i-love-my-church

**The problem**

http://site.com/groups/studies/foo displays the 404 template, but incorrectly returns a 200 response. (http://cl.ly/image/3E3U1N2X2j1L)

EE Docs state that EE will only [evaluate the first two segments](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html#page) unless used in conjunction with the require_entry parameter. Unfortunately, using this doesn't change the header.

**The code**

groups/_studies-collection:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="groups_study" url_title="{segment_3}" require_entry="yes" dynamic="off" status="Featured|Open"}

    Content Here

    {if no_results}
        {redirect="404"}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

groups/studies:

```
{if segment_3}
    {if segment_4}
        {embed="groups/_studies-entry"}
    {if:else}
        {exp:md_detect_page_type url_segment="{segment_3}"}
            {if pagination_page}
                {embed="groups/_studies-list"}
            {if:else}
                {embed="groups/_studies-collection"}
            {/if}
        {/exp:md_detect_page_type}
    {/if}
{if:else}
    {embed="newspring:groups/_studies-list"}
{/if}
```

Any clarity on this issue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's also in the bug reports, but there is a note in the [changelog](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html) for 2.9.1 :

> Fixed a bug in the 404 redirect behavior when used inside a no_results
>   tag on an embedded template.

This might be your issue if it works as expected outside of an embed.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I believe this is a similar, but different issue. There was a bug I also ran into on 2.9.0 where a 404 would embed a layout twice. I've tried to implement a similar bug fix, but to no avail. I'll take another look just in case!

Answer (score 0):

The no results conditional doesn't necessarily mean it's a 404 <del>and the fact you have a template called "404" doesn't mean that EE will assume it requires a 404 header - it's just another template</del>.

The strict URLs setting will mean any URL not picked up natively by templates will get the 404 header assigned to it - your URL on the other hand is being passed through a template.

[Edit - seeing as the native 404 redirect isn't working...]

You need to drop a plugin into your 404 template to correctly, try one of these:
http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=404+redirect+header&addon_version_support=ee2

Comment: According to EE docs, the {redirect="404"} is supposed to display the 404 page and send 404 headers. It's important to note that the "404" isn't an actual template, but rather a reserved name that can be used with the {redirect} variable. https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#redirect

Comment: Doh!  Must read question more closely!!!  Ho hum, as a work around you could use one of the add-ons I suggested :P